# Pass N-dimensional array as parameter

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, parameters

I have n-dimensional array which I am creating by using:

```
var arrayND = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), sqs.Select(n => n.Count).ToArray());
```

I don't know the number of dimensions at compile time. Is there a way to pass the array as a parameter when I don't know the number of dimensions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.Array` class is the base class for all arrays in the CLR. You can pass it as your parameter.